# Match By ObjectId In PySpark(Spark) With Python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pyspark

I am Trying this Pipeline in PySpark

```
pipeline = json.dumps([
                    {
                        '$match': {
                            'board_id': {
                                '$in': ["5f8405c81f70ae6a8a42b9b7"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ])
df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").option("pipeline",pipeline).format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")\
    .load()
```

But There is no Error And No Rows

Where i am Wrong ?

Thank's

Comment: `$in` is type sensitive, does it work if you convert that string to and ObjectID before matching?